# Import a delimited file with field values containing an escaped delimiter

Tags: postgresql, csv, pgloader

Given a delimited file in the following format

- fields delimited by a pipe char `|`
- text fields are unquoted
- some text field values contain an escaped pipe `\|`, an escaped line feed `\\n` or escaped carriage return `\\r`

```
1|text containing the pipe \| character|3
                           ^^^
```

what the correct combination of `pgloader` options might be to successfully load this file?

I tried

```
pgloader --type csv --field "field1,field2,field3" \
--with "fields terminated by '|'" \
--with "fields not enclosed" \
path/to/file.csv \
postgresql://user@host:port/dbname?tablename=schema.table
```

Which obviously didn't work for me as `pgloader` sees four fields instead of three.

Comment: @DimitriFontaine Any insights on how to overcome this would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You should specify escape character, cause by default it is double-quot.

Try following command:

```
pgloader --type csv \
         --field "field1,field2,field3" \
         --with "fields terminated by '|'" \
         --with "fields escaped by '\'" \
         path/to/file.csv \
         postgresql://user@host:port/dbname?tablename=schema.table
```

Comment: I didn't mention that in the question but I tried this option both with `'\'` and a hex code `'0x5C'`. It has no effect at least when spelled this way.

Comment: I see. Looks line csv not allow just escape delimiter character. Need quote filed with it. F. ex. ```1|"text containing the pipe | character"|3```